# Learning Undergrad Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics, relativity, education

I am an undergrad physics student who has finished the first year curriculum: very basic mechanics and thermal physics; basic linear algebra; basic multivariable calculus and differential equations; and basic electromagnetism/relativity (with very basic quantum physics).

The goal that I want to achieve is understanding of following fields in physics:

1. Dynamics (Hamiltonian, Lagrangian, Fluids, tc...)
2. Field Theory
3. Quantum Mechanics
4. Statistical Mechanics/Thermodynamics
5. Special/General Relativity
6. Astro/Cosmological Physics
7. Standard Model of Particle Physics

I have all the resources in the library/professors at my University.

What I want to know from this post are:

1. Which books I should get from the library for each fields in physics I have listed above.  If it is possible, please suggest a book from beginners-intermediate-advanced section so that I can work from one to the next when I've done with more basic one.
2. In which order should I learn?  (rearrange 1-7 on the choices above or feel free to add if you have suggestions)
3. Your opinion on this stupid (one might think) challenge.

The thing is that I could've taken a course and study, but due to the prerequisitse and things, I can't.
I don't want to wait another year or two years to learn those fields.

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to the Physics SE. The question I've linked is a placeholder for resource requests. It includes lots of recommendations on books for learning physics.

Comment: I couldn't figure out where the link is. But now I did. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are at the university now, you could register to take the classes offered by the university in the seven fields you listed. Each class will have it's own recommendations for textbooks. There are no magical textbooks. What really helps is to have a good teacher (hopefully the professor/instructor in class) who can explain the difficult points along the way.

Comment: The thing is that I could've taken a course and study, but due to the pre requisite and things, some of it, I can't.  

I don't want to wait another year or two years to learn those fields.

Comment: Well, why don't you register for the pre-requisites, because they are probably required for good reason. And to fill your time you can check out the myriad books listed in the link appended to your question (the link near the edits that marks the question as a duplicate).  ...anyways, it's a marathon, not a sprint.

Comment: Good luck, @Tom.